# SQL Server Project advanced publish settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I want to publish my database project, But I am unable to check any check box  ex:"Do not drop tables"..etc under drop menu in Advanced Publish settings while publishing. Please help me on this issue. I am using VS 2017 SSDT.

Comment: share some screenshots

Answer (score 2):

You would need to tick "Drop objects in target but not in source" in order to enable "Do not drop" options.

[image: Click here to see image]